# How to add ripple animation in imageView?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-imageview, rippledrawable

I'm trying to show a ripple animation in imageView before loading the image from the server.

I tried below code:

```
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

// Create a RippleDrawable with a solid color background and no foreground
        RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = new RippleDrawable(
                ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK), // Ripple color
                null, // Background drawable
                null // Foreground drawable
        );

// Create an AnimationDrawable that wraps the RippleDrawable
        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();
        animationDrawable.addFrame(rippleDrawable, 1000); // Add the RippleDrawable, with a duration of 1000 ms
        animationDrawable.setOneShot(false); // Set the animation to loop indefinitely

// Set the AnimationDrawable as the background of the ImageView
        imageView.setBackground(animationDrawable);

// Start the animation
        
        animationDrawable.start();
```

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**This is not working**

Comment: How is the image load started? Does the user click the image view? It looks like you want to show the ripple effect on a loop. Is that right?

Comment: @Cheticamp yes I want to show it in loop

Comment: _RippleDrawable_ does its own animation. I am not sure how layering another animation on top is going to work. You can get the ripple to work with a touch if you take out the animation and just use the drawable as the background. You will also have to set `android:clickable="true"` on the _ImageView_. If you want a ripple-like effect, you will most likely need to make your own IMO.